# I can't create specific resolution layouts on android studio

Tags: android, layout, resolution

[image: This is what happens]

I can create one layout for a specific resolution (for example 320x480) but then that layout applies to all devices, even devices with higher resolutions than that! Why does this happen on android studio? How can I make so that layout doesn't apply to devices with higher resolutions?

Thanks.

Comment: This is wrong approach. Read this docs first: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: There's so much info in that page, I already read it before but I got out empty handed, I just want to know how to create to specific resolutions (320x480, 480x800, 720x1280, 1080x1920)

Thanks...

Comment: what for? If you understand the page I linked to (and also read all it refers to) then you figure out that this is no-no idea. Also you may read about resource qualifiers there yet still - this is **wrong** aproach unless you are in 0,0001% of those who know they need it. I doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna make a density based apk, please use split function in your Gradle. And build APK.